# Can a function know from where it is exectuted?

Tags: powershell

`$MyInvocation` can be used to identify where the source of a script is located.

How can a function do the same?

```
function whereami {
    Write-Host $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path  # produces nothing
}

Write-Host $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
whereami
```

The C programmer would use `__FILE__`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `$PSCommandPath` which returns the full path to the script being executed.

Note that the script must be saved as a file before this will work in the ISE.

```
function whereami {
    $PSCommandPath
}

Write-Host $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
whereami
```

Returns:

```
PS C:\Users\> C:\Users\somescript.ps1
C:\Users\somescript.ps1
C:\Users\somescript.ps1
```

Comment: `$PSCommandPath` does return the source location in a function, but `$MyInvocation.PSCommandPath` returns the script location, not the function.

Comment: Is the function not in the script? Or are you dot sourcing it in from another script?

Comment: Function is from a module in a file far, far away. $PSCommandPath works.

Comment: Thanks i'll amend.